# grid layout centred div between two div's

Tags: html, css

I've managed to centre a div element that's in my row class but when I add two other div's on the left and right side I'm unable to have the elements flow in their right positions(one on the far left and one on the far right).

here is my code on [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iFrdl)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-12">
        Left
    </div>

    <div class="col-3-12 centred">
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>  


     <div class="col-1-12 offset-10-12">
         right
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you try using <span></span> instead of divs. Divs line things up vertically while spans arrange them horizontally

Comment: @stackPopper why don't you make an example with my code. I tried using spans and I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to play with `offset-` and `col-` classes:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-12">left</div>
    <div class="col-4-12 offset-3-12">Duis aute ...</div>
    <div class="col-1-12 offset-3-12">right</div>
</div>
```

Note that if your grid is 12 columns based you need the sum of offsets and cols to be exactly 12 to make it fit.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EBZHJ/

Comment: Yeah that way works but really want to know if I can use the centred class and make it work that way do you have any other ideas for centred class to work.